# UIWebView and .ics file on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4

I am having trouble detecting an .ics file in my custom browser on the iPad. I want to be able to open the .ics file in the calendar app.

In Safari, you get the option to "Open in..." or "Open in Calendar".

I want to be able to do the same...is that possible?

Thanks